# Meaning of "It of"

Tags: meaning, grammar, expressions

I'm not sure that's an actual expression because Google has found no similiar entries. It may be just a typo. But here it goes:

"Viewed as a language, theory has no substantive content; **it of** tautologies." (p. 4 of *Essays in Positive Economics* by Milton Friedman).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a faulty rendering and this is not linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faulty copy.  Really it says

> Viewed as a language, theory has no substantive content; it is a set of tautologies.

Comment: This is useful only to OP and should be a comment.